# How to add hyperlink on JSON code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a json file created for adding a FAQ section on the website.
How to add the following link on "To be added here" Section: https://www.secure.awl-in.net/shellcash/Registration.aspx. I'm not sure how to use Hyperlink code in body.

```
{
    "question": "How to register the Shell petro card on website?",
    "answer": "<p>Steps to Register the card on Shell website</p> 
    <ul><li> Click On the link: 

    *** To be added here ***

    (https://www.secure.awl-in.net/shellcash/Registration.aspx) </li>
    <li>At Petro Bunk, <strong>Swipe the card > choose balance enquiry > enter your pin</strong>. You would get to know the balance.</li></ul>"
}
```

Comment: If you search online for the words `hyperlink code` you'll get exactly what you're looking for in less time than it took to post this question ;)

Comment: Hi @vi5ion I did that but, I do know how to do it on JSON. I tried using Anchor tags as like in HTML and PHP it didn't work.

Comment: @vi5ion , I don't know web programming. I do have some idea by such practices of copy pasting HTML codes and is easy to understand. If I would have got exactly what I want by searching online. I need not to post this in here.

Comment: But what you're adding is HTML. Yes it is inside a JSON object, but the String value for `answer` is plain HTML, so a plain HTML anchor tag should work: `{ "question": "How to register the Shell petro card on website?", "answer": "<p>Steps to Register the card on Shell website</p><ul><li>Click On the link: <a href='https://www.secure.awl-in.net/shellcash/Registration.aspx'>https://www.secure.awl-in.net/shellcash/Registration.aspx</a></li><li>At Petro Bunk, <strong>Swipe the card > choose balance enquiry > enter your pin</strong>. You would get to know the balance.</li></ul>" }`

Comment: Thank you very much @vi5ion I works fine.  I tried the same before posting this question. But as like in HTML I was using " " for the link on anchor tag instead ' '.